# Iterating through list within a list and only outputs last value

Tags: python, list, loops, chess

I have multiple lists (Strategies) of chess moves in one big list that are being iterated through, move by move.

```
for list in Strategies:
           for j in list:
               self.move_sequence = j
```

It is only outputting the last move in the entire list, but I would like to start from the first move and move towards the end one-by-one. Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's only using the last element because that's exactly what you've written it to do. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
for list in Strategies:
    
    for j in list:
       self.move_sequence += j
       
    print(self.move_sequence)
    self.move_sequence = ''
```